# Switch aws cli to cross account with mfa enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Is there a way to access cross account from aws credential which has mfa enabled?

I am able to switch account from aws management console, I want to do the same from cli.

Tried updating .aws/config file as per the link below.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-cli.html

Getting an error: The config profile (CrossAccountSignin) could not be found. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this - the `~/.aws/credentials` file and the `~/.aws/config` file.

Lets say you have an IAM user `my-user-id` in account `987654321098` and want to assume a role called `my-assumed-role` in account `0123456789012`

The `~/.aws/credentials` file contains a profile with the IAM Command Line User credentials - access key id and secret access key - from `my-user-id`. For example:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR
aws_secret_access_key=SeCrEtKeY
region=ap-southeast-2
output=json
```

The `~/.aws/config` file contains a profile with the ARN of the cross account role and the IAM User's MFA serial number, along with any other session options. For example:

```
[profile cross-account-role]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/my-assumed-role
source_profile = default
mfa_serial = arn:aws:iam::987654321098:mfa/my-user-id
region=ap-southeast-2
s3 = 
    signature_version = s3v4
role_session_name = my-session
```

To assume the cross account role with the CLI we append the profile of the role from `~/.aws/config` e.g. `--profile cross-account-role` to the command.

As the `source_profile` is default, it will use the credentials of the IAM user `my-user-id` with MFA from account `987654321098` to assume the *my-assumed-role* role in the target account `0123456789012`

For example

```
myuser@myost:~$ aws sts get-caller-identity --profile cross-account-role
Enter MFA code for arn:aws:iam::987654321098:mfa/my-user-id:
{
    "UserId": "AROAABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR:my-user-id",
    "Account": "0123456789012",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::0123456789012:assumed-role/my-assumed-role/my-session"
}
```

The CLI will prompt you to enter your MFA code and then provide the output. The session will last by default for 60 minutes and it is cached. During this time the any further CLI commands will not need to prompt again for a MFA code.